# Dynamics 365 API Call Limits

Tags: dynamics-365

does anybod know how the API calls in Dynamics 365 are counted?

In particular the Organizationservice.Execute with ExecuteMultiple Request.
Is this counted as one Request or is each Request inside the Requestcollecion counted by it's own?

Thanks
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations), CRUD operations are counted in API limit.  Execute multiple is basically a wrapper provided to improve performance of bulk operations. Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/org-service/use-executemultiple-improve-performance-bulk-data-load) for details of ExecuteMultiple.

In nutshell, ExecuteMultiple behaves as if each request executed separately. So API limit will count all the requests executed by ExecuteMultiple and not one.

Answer (score 0):

Every ExecuteMultiple can have a maximum of 1000 Request. But you can run multiple executeMultiple. Once there was a limit of 2 concurrent request, but not it is removed
From docs:

> There was once a limit on the number of concurrent ExecuteMultiple requests. The limit was 2. This was removed because service protection limits made it unnecessary. For more information: Service Protection API Limits.